# OpenGLES 1.0 Lighting : Specular Light shine only one side of the object

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am developing an android app with OpenGLES but when i add a specular  light the object shine only one side of object while i use the same code and a little modify for complatible with glut it work fine.

Here is my Code in activity

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Handler handlerz = new Handler();
private ArrayList<Bottle> objecttable = new ArrayList<Bottle>();
private boolean start = true;
//ambientlight color
private float[] amblightcolor = {0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,1};
//diffuselight color
private float[] diflightcolor = {1f,1f,1f,1};
//specularlight color
private float[] specularcolor = {1,1,1,1};
//Position of light
private float[] lightpos = {0.0f,0.0f,1f,0};
//direction of light
private float[] lightdir = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f };
//FloatBuffer to use from light array
private FloatBuffer ambientlight;
private FloatBuffer diffuselight;
private FloatBuffer specularlight;
private FloatBuffer positionlight;
private FloatBuffer lightdirection;
private Random r = new Random();
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        //Make every bottle in list spin more 1 angle for every 50 ms
         for (Bottle b : objecttable){
             b.angle += 1;
             if (b.angle == 360)
                 b.angle = 0;
         }
      handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
     }
};
private Runnable runnablez = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
    //Make every bottle in list move in z axis and if bottle's z is more than 0 it reset to -10 and random position
     if (!start){
         if (!objecttable.isEmpty())
             for (Bottle b : objecttable){
                 if (b.cz >= 0){
                    float factorx;
                    float factory;
                    if (r.nextBoolean())
                        factorx = r.nextFloat();
                    else
                        factorx = r.nextFloat() *-1;
                    if (r.nextBoolean())
                        factory = r.nextFloat();
                    else
                        factory = r.nextFloat() *-1;
                    b.cx = factorx;
                    b.cy = factory;
                    b.cz = -10;
                 }
                 else
                    //move rate = speed
                     b.cz += b.speed;
             }
     }
      handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
     }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Panel p = new Panel(this);
    p.setRenderer(new Renderer());
    setContentView(p);
    handler.post(runnable);
    handlerz.post(runnablez);
    //Set model to draw from data
    Bottle.setModel(this);
}
public class Panel extends GLSurfaceView{
    public Panel(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
public class Renderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer{

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GLES10.glShadeModel(GLES10.GL_SMOOTH);
        GLES10.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        GLES10.glEnable(GLES10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        //initial light properties
        initlight();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GLES10.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        GLES10.glMatrixMode(GLES10.GL_PROJECTION);
        GLES10.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f,
                (float) width / (float) height,
                0.1f, 100.0f);
        GLES10.glMatrixMode(GLES10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GLES10.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // At begining of program
        if (start){
            initDrawing();
            start = false;
        }
        else
            drawobject();
    }
    //Make a list for bottle there are new 5 bottles to add with random position
    private void initDrawing(){
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
            float factorx;
            float factory;
            if (r.nextBoolean())
                factorx = r.nextFloat();
            else
                factorx = r.nextFloat() *-1;
            if (r.nextBoolean())
                factory = r.nextFloat();
            else
                factory = r.nextFloat() *-1;
            objecttable.add(new Bottle(factorx,factory,-10-i,(short) (20*i)));
        }
    }
    //initial light properties
    private void initlight(){
        ByteBuffer ambl = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(amblightcolor.length * 4);
        ambl.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        ambientlight = ambl.asFloatBuffer();
        ambientlight.put(amblightcolor);
        ambientlight.position(0);

        ByteBuffer difl = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(diflightcolor.length * 4);
        difl.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        diffuselight = difl.asFloatBuffer();
        diffuselight.put(diflightcolor);
        diffuselight.position(0);

        ByteBuffer spcl = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(specularcolor.length * 4);
        spcl.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        specularlight = spcl.asFloatBuffer();
        specularlight.put(specularcolor);
        specularlight.position(0);

        ByteBuffer lpos = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lightpos.length * 4);
        lpos.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        positionlight = lpos.asFloatBuffer();
        positionlight.put(lightpos);
        positionlight.position(0);

        ByteBuffer ldir = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(lightdir.length * 4);
        ldir.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        lightdirection = ldir.asFloatBuffer();
        lightdirection.put(lightdir);
        lightdirection.position(0);

        GLES10.glFrontFace(GLES10.GL_CCW);
        GLES10.glLightfv(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0, GLES10.GL_AMBIENT, ambientlight);
        GLES10.glLightfv(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0, GLES10.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuselight);
        GLES10.glLightfv(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0, GLES10.GL_SPECULAR, specularlight);
        GLES10.glLightfv(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0, GLES10.GL_POSITION, positionlight);
        GLES10.glLightfv(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0, GLES10.GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, lightdirection);
        GLES10.glLightf(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0,GLES10.GL_SPOT_CUTOFF,15.0f);
        GLES10.glMaterialfv(GLES10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GLES10.GL_SPECULAR, specularlight);
        GLES10.glMaterialf(GLES10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GLES10.GL_SHININESS,128);          
    }
    //draw every bottles in list using blend and light effect
    private void drawobject(){
            GLES10.glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GLES10.glEnable(GLES10.GL_BLEND);
            GLES10.glBlendFunc (GLES10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            GLES10.glEnable(GLES10.GL_LIGHTING);
            GLES10.glEnable(GLES10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
            GLES10.glMaterialfv(GLES10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GLES10.GL_SPECULAR, specularlight);
            GLES10.glMaterialf(GLES10.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GLES10.GL_SHININESS,128);
            GLES10.glEnable(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0);
            GLES10.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            GLES10.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
            for(Bottle b : objecttable)
                    b.draw();
            GLES10.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            GLES10.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); 
            GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_BLEND);
            GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
            GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_LIGHT0);
            GLES10.glDisable(GLES10.GL_LIGHTING);
    }
}
```

Bottle class code

```
public class Bottle {
//center of bottle x , y and z
public float cx;
public float cy;
public float cz;
//Angle of bottle
public short angle = 0;
//bottle's speed to move in z axis
public float speed = 0.02f;
//3D model data
public static FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
public static FloatBuffer normalBuffer;
//3D model object use to import wavefront model to this object and make it to vertexBuffer and normalBuffer
public static BottleMdl Model;
public Bottle(float x, float y,float z,short ang) {
    cx = x;
    cy = y;
    cz = z;
    angle = ang;
}
//Bottle draw
public void draw(){
    GLES10.glPushMatrix();
    //translate the center of bottle
    GLES10.glTranslatef(cx, cy, cz);
    //Rotate the bottle by angle for making it spin
    GLES10.glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
    GLES10.glColor4f(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 0.8f);
    GLES10.glVertexPointer(3, GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    GLES10.glNormalPointer(GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, normalBuffer);
    GLES10.glDrawArrays(GLES10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, Model.numberofvertexs);
    GLES10.glPopMatrix();
}
//Set a model data to vertexbuffer and normalbuffer
public static void setModel(Context context){
    Model = new BottleMdl(context);
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Model.vertexs.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(Model.vertexs);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer nbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Model.normals.length * 4);
    nbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    normalBuffer = nbb.asFloatBuffer();
    normalBuffer.put(Model.normals);
    normalBuffer.position(0);
}
```

}

The program will install the light first then read data in object arraylist translate it by moving -z and rotate object in x-axis and draw.

The image should be like this in glut

http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z399/GalmTwo/glut_result.png

As you can see it shine in both side of bottle look like the light position is fixed

But here in android simulator

http://i1187.photobucket.com/albums/z399/GalmTwo/android_result.png

the first one is correct but when it flip to another side of bottle it not shine look like the light moving all the time but i'm very sure that i have set the light position before transform anything and in glut it work fine.

Please help me to solve this problem or give me an example code of specular light which can work fine in android i try to solve this problem all day but i can't
Thank you for help and sorry for my bad English.